# Client side certificate validation for NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, swagger, aws-api-gateway, client-certificates

I have developed a swagger-based REST api in NodeJS which lives in a AWS ElasticBeanstalk application. I am also proxying the api using an AWS gateway. I would like to make it so that my api only accepts requests that originate from the gateway. I have read this documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html and found many examples of how to do this with nginx and apache but nothing with node. I know the docs point to a couple of npm packages but the answer does not seem obvious to me. Does anybody have an example?

Comment: I've found a few examples on a quick google search. https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-certificate-auth or generic https://engineering.circle.com/https-authorized-certs-with-node-js-315e548354a2#.fcf8z7zev

Comment: API Gateway is just providing the PEM-encoded public cert that you can add to the server's CA. The server's CA is what controls which client certificates are accepted.

Comment: the npmjs link shows the code reading three files: server.key, server.pem and cacert.pem. Which of the three is the one that the API gateway provides?

Comment: The cert API Gateway provides goes in cacert.pem

Comment: thanks, and the other two are the cert and private key that i used to secure the beanstalk app?

Comment: Should be the server certs, which are usually signed by a trusted CA (self-signed won't work)

Comment: @JackKohn-AWS - Isn't the cert provided by the API Gateway an Intermediate cert ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-ruby.html#Puma

Comment: @fnCzar could you let me know how did you integrate the client certificate in your app.js file?